# Пытаюсь выполнить полученный Intent - говорит нет активности в манифесте

Tags: java, android, android-intent

У меня Intent формируется в сервисе, как результат работы, и передается в Activity:

```java
//В сервисе:
Intent details = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                            .setData(Uri.parse(url));
...
//через PendingIntent из сервиса передаем активности:
 pi.send(<класс сервиса>.this, 1, details);
```

В активности выводится диалог с кнопкой "Подробнее" с простым действием:

```java
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

При нажатии выдает ошибку:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
> activity class
> {класс сервиса};
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Что-то я в растерянности, почему так.

Comment: как результат работы можете использовать BroadcastReciever

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы ошибка ругается на то что эта активность не записана в манифесте чтобы это исправить перейдите в манифест и допишите эту строку `<activity android:name=".yourJavaOrKotlinClass"/>` Простите что оставил в виде ответа просто не хватает репутации ещё.

Comment: И активность и сервис в манифесте прописаны. Я создаю Intent в сервисе и передаю его через PendingIntent в активность. Сам Intent по идее никак не связан с классом сервиса, но при попытке выполнить ругается.